# Get all songs from music library on iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, mpmediaquery

I am writing small app that can play music. To get all songs I am using code below

```
 var songsArray: [MPMediaItem] = [MPMediaItem]()
 var mediaQuery = MPMediaQuery()
 songsArray = MPMediaQuery.songsQuery().items as [MPMediaItem]

 for songItem in songsArray {            
     var song: myMusicItem? = myMusicItem(songTitle: songItem.title, songAlbum: songItem.albumTitle, songArtist: songItem.albumArtist, songGenre: songItem.genre)

     retArray.append(song!)
 }

 println(String(format:"Number of songs:\t%i", retArray.count))
```

And the problem is that `retArray` has more items than actually is in my library. Does anyone have an idea why this situation is happening?

Comment: What you mean by more Item ? Is that array contains duplicate items ? How you are calling this method and from where ?

Comment: More items means if my music library have 900 songs, `MPMediaQuery.songsQuery().items as [MPMediaItem]` returns more than 1000 items. I don't have duplicated items.Method with this code is called on button touch. And array does not contains duplicate items.

Comment: Maybe videos? "A media item represents a single piece of media (such as one song or one video podcast) in the iPod library." https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMediaItem_ClassReference/#//apple_ref/c/data/MPMediaItemPropertyPersistentID

Comment: Well... but I am using MPMediaQuery.songsQuery() so I think only songs should be taken, not videos or podcasts. I have one more idea - what about songs in cloud? In settings I set option to not to show items that are in cloud only. Can this be it?

Answer (score 0):

As you suggested in the comments, iCloud media items, which are included by default, could be the difference.

Try adding this filter predicate to your query to not include iCloud items:

```
query.addFilterPredicate(MPMediaPropertyPredicate(value: false, forProperty: MPMediaItemPropertyIsCloudItem))
```